# Allow row selecting in a dataGridview but don't allow cell selecting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

I would like to allow row selecting in a DataGridView ( C#, WinForm ) and don't allow cell selecting.

Is there a way to do this please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check your Properties window in Visual Studio after selecting the `DataGridView`. You'll notice a property called `SelectionMode`. Set it to `FullRowSelect`.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
this.DataGridView.Columns["Text"].ReadOnly = true;
```

`DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect` means individual cells cannot be selected.

`DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly = true` means that cells cannot be double-clicked into.